# Do shorter names exist for "one-to-many", "one-to-one", "many-to-many" relationships?

Tags: naming-convention

In terms of generic variable naming or even everyday geek discussion, do shorter and "cleaner" terms exist for one-to-one, one-to-many, and many-to-many relationships.

For example, in discussion of religion, one can say "relating to many denominations of Christianity", but it's much shorter to say, "ecumenical". In computer science, "Your arrangement of words and punctuation is incorrect" is less awkwardly said, "You have a syntax error."
Do such terms exist for the common database cardinalities?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as verbal communication, there are none that I'm aware of. There are symbols for writing but those wouldn't be of any help for verbal communication.